# Shuffling the DOM

Tags: jquery, shuffle

I'm using the shuffle script below to randomise the order of some div's on my site.

http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/shuffling-the-dom/

The script works but only randomises the **`.content div`**, not **`.step`**, so the images get mixed up.

Is there a way to select *all* the content in `.step`?

```
<div class="step">
<div class="content">
  <h2>title</h2>
  <p>text</p>
  <a href="#">link</a>
</div>
<img src="./images/1.png" />
</div>

$( '.step div' ).shuffle();
```

Comment: Why arent you shuffling the `.step` ie. `$('.step').shuffle();` ?

Comment: When I use ('.step') the shuffle doesn't work.

Comment: Old question, but it's still not clear what the expected behaviour should be; in the given markup, `'.step div'` only selects one item and after randomisation it won't move.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( '.step' ).shuffle();
```

just remove the inner div selector.

Answer (score 0):

i read the link you posted did you used the plugin $.fn.shuffle
or the second one "untested say by the author"   if you used the first one as i think
the you should read carefully at the top page of the link it says

**

> I was recently looking for a decent way of shuffling a set of
>   elements. I found a jQuery plugin which claimed to do exactly that but
>   unfortunately it only works if all elements are direct descendants of
>   a single parent, like all list items under an unordered list.

**

and i tried it on my netbeans after including the plugin my code HTML was

```
<div class="content">
  <p>text1</p>
</div>
 <div class="content">
  <p>text2</p>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <p>text3</p>
</div>


<div class="content">
  <p>text4</p>
</div>
 <div class="content">
  <p>text5</p>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <p>text6</p>
  <img src="./images/1.png" />
</div>
```

but again
it only works if all elements are direct descendants of a single parent, like all list items under an unordered list

it works fine but be precise

i used the script below ,and **put the image inside div element**

```
 $("document").ready(function() {
       $("div").shuffle();
 });
```

the output

text5

text3

text4

text2

text1

text6

and they randomaly  shuffled

Answer (score 0):

`$('div.step').shuffle();` should help.

Could you show your full HTML?